# External CSS Style sheet doesn't work when running on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have main.html that links to web.css and when I run the main file it runs fine with the CSS but when I run the whole thing on google app engine, it doesn't apply the CSS. From the GAE logs I get

```
INFO     2012-05-10 01:58:46,526 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /web.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2012-05-10 01:58:46,540 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This is in my html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hi </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my code

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
import re
from datetime import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from utility_functions import valid_username, valid_password, valid_email

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def render(self, link, values={}):
        je = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

        template = je.get_template(link)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(values))        


class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('main.html')


handlers = [('/', MainPage)]
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(handlers, debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post your app.yaml file? Did you remember to include a static file directory that contains web.css?

Comment: Hi, I didn't know I had to do that..but now works :) thanks

Comment: Great! I've added an answer below for anyone that might come across your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this question, static files should be declared with a [static file handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers). For example, this serves a directory called css, which maps the directory `css` in the root of your application directory to a publicly available `css` directory at the root of your appspot domain:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

Comment: For anyone still having trouble after reading this answer, let me add that the **order** of declarations is important (from [official doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Required_elements): *the first mapping whose pattern matches the URL is the one used to handle the request*), so you should  add it before the `- url: /.*` declaration.

Answer (score 4):

add this to your `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /web.css
  static_files: web.css
  upload: web.css
```

Comment: @voscausa: lenik's answer is even *more* correct, in that it doesn't need to (and fail to) mention changing the OP's HTML to use the absolute path starting with `/css/` instead of the path it uses now; this answer certainly isn't worthy of a downvote in any case.